# Convert URI to GUID

Tags: c#, hash, guid, uri

What is a good way to convert a file path (URI) into a System.Guid? I'd like to minimize the possibility of a collision, but I'm happy with a reasonably unique hashing (probably never more than a few dozen/hundred items in the database)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need. Hash URI with md5 or sha1 and that's all. GUIDs are not for hashing things. They  meant to be created unique independently of everything else.

Comment: Appreciate the spanking, but I've got to retrofit these into a system which already depends on Guids. EDIT: ah, I see md5 creates a 128bit number, which equals a Guid. I can go from here I think.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think there may be a collision with "natively generated" GUIDs this way if you generate a real lot of them

Comment: hi, I am interested in knowing what program OR how you would convert the URI to md5 hash? is there a utility somewhere in VS? thanks!

Comment: @VoodooChild, have a look at System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider

Comment: Look at the implementations of the v3 (MD5) and v5 (SHA-1) UUIDs in RFC 4122, http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt uuid_create_md5_from_name and in Python, http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/uuid.py?view=markup

Comment: If someone is asking how to hash something in .NET that's really useless to send him to RFCs...

Answer (score 8):

The "correct" way (according to [RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) §4.3) is to create a name-based UUID. The advantage of doing this (over just using a MD5 hash) is that these are guaranteed not to collide with non-named-based UUIDs, and have a very (very) small possibility of collision with other name-based UUIDs.

There's no native support in the .NET Framework for creating these, but by using code [similar to this](https://github.com/LogosBible/Logos.Utility/blob/master/src/Logos.Utility/GuidUtility.cs), you could create a GUID as follows:

```
Guid guid = GuidUtility.Create(GuidUtility.UrlNamespace, filePath);
```

To reduce the risk of collisions with other GUIDs even further, you could create a private GUID to use as the namespace ID (instead of using the URL namespace ID defined in the RFC).

Comment: Note that *similar* is the operative word in *similar to this*. If you want your UUIDs to match the test case of the RFC (which, disappointingly, only has one test case for type 3, and none for type 5) then it's necessary to change the code which manipulates `newGuid[6]` to instead manipulate `newGuid[7]`, and to remove `SwapByteOrder`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: RFC4122 is incorrect and has errata that fixes the C code (http://rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=4122&eid=1352). If this implementation is not fully compliant with RFC4122 and its errata, please provide further details; I would like to make it follow the standard.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the option of a centralized registry/database, you could maintain a GUID <-> URL resolver and generate a new GUID for each URL you need.  This would use GUIDs the way they are intended, minimizing probability of collision with natively-generated GUIDs.

Comment: Michael, excellent suggestion. I'll keep this in mind in case I run into issues with the md5 encryption.